# Convert nested JSON to CSV in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, csv

Have seen a lot of thread but unable to found the solution for mine. I want to convert one nested JSON to CSV in Python 2.7. The sample JSON file is as below:

```
sample.json # My JSON file that mainly contains a firewall rule

"rulebase": [
    {
        "from": 1, 
        "name": "test-policy", 
        "rulebase": [
            {
                "action": "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c473", 
                "action-settings": {}, 
                "comments": "FYI", 
                "content": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "content-direction": "any", 
                "content-negate": false, 
                "custom-fields": {
                    "field-1": "", 
                    "field-2": "", 
                    "field-3": ""
                }, 
                "destination": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "destination-negate": false, 
                "domain": {
                    "domain-type": "domain", 
                    "name": "SMC User", 
                    "uid": "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
                }, 
                "enabled": true, 
                "hits": {
                    "first-date": {
                        "iso-8601": "2016-09-04T22:21-0500", 
                        "posix": 1473045718000
                    }, 
                    "last-date": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-03-19T03:37-0500", 
                        "posix": 1521448660000
                    }, 
                    "level": "low", 
                    "percentage": "0%", 
                    "value": 36737474
                }, 
                "install-on": [
                    "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476"
                ], 
                "meta-info": {
                    "creation-time": {
                        "iso-8601": "2016-09-15T12:42-0500", 
                        "posix": 1473961370382
                    }, 
                    "creator": "System", 
                    "last-modifier": "admin", 
                    "last-modify-time": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-08-30T18:36-0500", 
                        "posix": 1535672186192
                    }, 
                    "lock": "unlocked", 
                    "validation-state": "ok"
                }, 
                "rule-number": 1, 
                "service": [
                    "ef245528-9a3d-11d6-9eaa-3e5a6fdd6a6a", 
                    "dff4f7ba-9a3d-11d6-91c1-3e5a6fdd5151", 
                    "24bee257-6b37-49bb-99aa-557d993a0e48", 
                    "97aeb45c-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30", 
                    "97aeb471-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "service-negate": false, 
                "source": [
                    "697bb7e0-0dfe-4070-a21a-68858daae98c", 
                    "349fb05c-99b2-4fb2-aea6-7b447d0e661c"
                ], 
                "source-negate": true, 
                "time": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "track": {
                    "accounting": false, 
                    "alert": "none", 
                    "per-connection": true, 
                    "per-session": false, 
                    "type": "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d"
                }, 
                "type": "access-rule", 
                "uid": "2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1", 
                "vpn": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "action": "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c472", 
                "action-settings": {
                    "enable-identity-captive-portal": false
                }, 
                "comments": "", 
                "content": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "content-direction": "any", 
                "content-negate": false, 
                "custom-fields": {
                    "field-1": "", 
                    "field-2": "", 
                    "field-3": ""
                }, 
                "destination": [
                    "b17d4573-ad1a-4126-ae6d-c874ea919cda", 
                    "5b78417c-64ed-4566-9c76-e4e1af25a9ae", 
                    "acb8d280-2ec4-46b1-be9f-c676fa255fb5"
                ], 
                "destination-negate": false, 
                "domain": {
                    "domain-type": "domain", 
                    "name": "SMC User", 
                    "uid": "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
                }, 
                "enabled": true, 
                "hits": {
                    "level": "zero", 
                    "percentage": "0%", 
                    "value": 0
                }, 
                "install-on": [
                    "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476"
                ], 
                "meta-info": {
                    "creation-time": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-07-25T16:27-0500", 
                        "posix": 1532554044090
                    }, 
                    "creator": "admin", 
                    "last-modifier": "admin", 
                    "last-modify-time": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-08-31T16:00-0500", 
                        "posix": 1535749228997
                    }, 
                    "lock": "unlocked", 
                    "validation-state": "ok"
                }, 
                "name": "tom@gmail.com", 
                "rule-number": 2, 
                "service": [
                    "18ec9eaa-1657-4240-ab97-5f234623336b"
                ], 
                "service-negate": false, 
                "source": [
                    "293ef5ba-5235-464e-9247-bda26229a998", 
                    "b503873f-0c5f-4798-b87a-dd6ed4561b40"
                ], 
                "source-negate": false, 
                "time": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "track": {
                    "accounting": false, 
                    "alert": "none", 
                    "per-connection": true, 
                    "per-session": false, 
                    "type": "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d"
                }, 
                "type": "access-rule", 
                "uid": "fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba", 
                "vpn": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "action": "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c472", 
                "action-settings": {
                    "enable-identity-captive-portal": false
                }, 
                "comments": "FYI", 
                "content": [
                    "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30"
                ], 
                "content-direction": "any", 
                "content-negate": false, 
                "custom-fields": {
                    "field-1": "", 
                    "field-2": "", 
                    "field-3": ""
                }, 
                "destination": [
                    "b17d4573-ad1a-4126-ae6d-c874ea919cda", 
                    "5b78417c-64ed-4566-9c76-e4e1af25a9ae", 
                    "acb8d280-2ec4-46b1-be9f-c676fa255fb5"
                ], 
                "destination-negate": false, 
                "domain": {
                    "domain-type": "domain", 
                    "name": "SMC User", 
                    "uid": "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde"
                }, 
                "enabled": true, 
                "hits": {
                    "first-date": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-03-14T14:55-0500", 
                        "posix": 1521057347000
                    }, 
                    "last-date": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-03-19T03:58-0500", 
                        "posix": 1521449932000
                    }, 
                    "level": "low", 
                    "percentage": "0%", 
                    "value": 11801
                }, 
                "install-on": [
                    "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476"
                ], 
                "meta-info": {
                    "creation-time": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-03-14T09:47-0500", 
                        "posix": 1521038846894
                    }, 
                    "creator": "System", 
                    "last-modifier": "admin", 
                    "last-modify-time": {
                        "iso-8601": "2018-08-31T16:17-0500", 
                        "posix": 1535750234317
                    }, 
                    "lock": "unlocked", 
                    "validation-state": "ok"
                }, 
                "name": "tom1@gmail.com", 
             }
```

From the above JSON file my requirement to redirect keys {uid, name, rule-number, comments, destination, source, hits.last-date}, etc. with their values  to CSV basically.

By following the below code, I was able to generate the CSV but seems that is only parsing header, nothing else.

```
import json
import csv

def get_leaves(item, key=None):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        leaves = []
        for i in item.keys():
            leaves.extend(get_leaves(item[i], i))
        return leaves
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        leaves = []
        for i in item:
            leaves.extend(get_leaves(i, key))
        return leaves
    else:
        return [(key, item)]

with open('sample.json') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
write_header = True

for entry in json.load(f_input):
    leaf_entries = sorted(get_leaves(entry))

    if write_header:
        csv_output.writerow([k for k, v in leaf_entries])
        write_header = False

    csv_output.writerows([v for k, v in leaf_entries.items()])
```

Please guide me as I am very much new to Python scripting.

Comment: Update your JSON and code with a working example.  I made an attempt to get it running, but not sure my output is what you are getting.  Answers should be able to save your input and code as files and just run them with no changes.  The JSON is not complete and the code gives indentation errors.  Added expected and actual output helps as well.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. The below code properly working and generating valid csv data from my complex JSON file.

```
# Generate CSV from JSON
fw_access_layers_data = open('show-access-layers.json', 'r')
fw_access_layers_parsed = json.loads(fw_access_layers_data.read())
access_layers = fw_access_layers_parsed['access-layers']
fw_access_layers_csv = open('show-access-layers.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(fw_access_layers_csv)
count = 0
for access_layer in access_layers:
if count == 0:
    header = access_layer.keys()
    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    count += 1
csvwriter.writerow(access_layer.values())
fw_access_layers_csv.close()
```

Thanks for your help mates.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there. You're just calling `csv_output.writerow()` on the list you created with `[v for k, v in leaf_entries]`. You should instead call `csv_output.writerows()`.

Information on these calls is available here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects

Comment: By updating `csv_output.writerow([v for k, v in leaf_entries])` the output redirects each letter to each cell in excel with no values.

Comment: Use `leaf_entries.items()` to for your dict from json

Comment: `csv_output.writerows([v for k, v in leaf_entries.items()])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` This is where it is stuck now.