# Parse multiple json value using pyjq, separated by comma

Tags: python, json, csv

Using pyjq i am able to parse values from json file. I need to format the output bit more so this can be exported to csv.

```
import json
import csv
import pyjq

emp_data = open('example.json', 'r')
emp_data_parsed = json.loads(emp_data.read())
emp = pyjq.all ('.base[].base[].uid, .base[].base[].name', emp_data_parsed)
print emp
```

The output I am getting

```
[u'2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1', u'fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba', u'4ecf6450-7307-466c-bf19-663ba2fbaf69', None, u'Tommy', u'Sam',
```

Expecting output as below so that can be written to a csv file.

```
uid,name
'2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1','None'
'fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba','Tommy'
'4ecf6450-7307-466c-bf19-663ba2fbaf69','Sam'
```

Following is the sample.json file

```
example.json
{
    "base": [
        { 
            "base": [
                {
                    "item-number": 1, 
                    "type": "access-item", 
                    "uid": "2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1",  
                    "usage": { 
                        "last-date": {
                            "iso-8601": "2018-03-19T03:58-0500", 
                        }, 
                    }, 

                    "item-number": 2, 
                    "name": "Tommy",
                    "type": "access-item", 
                    "uid": "fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba", 

                    "item-number": 3, 
                    "name": "Sam",
                    "type": "access-item", 
                    "uid": "4ecf6450-7307-466c-bf19-663ba2fbaf69", 
                    "usage": { 
                        "last-date": {
                            "iso-8601": "2018-03-21T07:21-0500", 
                        }, 
                    },
                }
            ], 
        }
    ], 
}
```

I am not sure otherthan pyjq, there is an way of doing this. If so please let me know.

Comment: Relevant [convert-nested-json-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428921/convert-nested-json-to-csv-in-python-2-7)

Comment: @stovfi, no this is to fetch only required values from each section and display or redirect to csv. The other post is to convert the whole json to csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: I need to format the output bit more so this can be exported to csv.

Can't test with `pyjp`, guess from the [Project description](https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/), try:

```
pyjq.all('.base[].base[] | {"uid": .uid, "item-number":.item-number}', emp_data_parsed)
```

---

Loop your JSON like this:

```
for rec in emp_data_parsed['base'][0]['base']:
    print("{}".format(rec))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> {'uid': '2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1', 'item-number': 1}, ... (omitted for brevity)
> {'uid': 'fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba', 'item-number': 2}, ... (omitted for brevity)
> {'uid': '4ecf6450-7307-466c-bf19-663ba2fbaf69', 'item-number': 3}, ... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

The Output is ready for `csv.DictWriter` read [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), for example:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['uid', 'item-number']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()

    for record in emp_data_parsed['base'][0]['base']:
        writer.writerow(record)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> uid,name
> 2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1,None
> fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba,Tommy
> 4ecf6450-7307-466c-bf19-663ba2fbaf69,Sam
> ```

Comment: Absolutely perfect @stovfl. Please just minor edit `with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file` with `with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:`. This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No i tried with `emp = pyjq.all('.base[].base[] | {"uid": .uid, "name": .name]}', emp_data_parsed)`. And it worked

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I know [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), Python wrapper for that is a good idea.

I use `jq` for my data processing. And also `grep`, `head` etc. :) When I need to work with CSV, I rather write a CSV-to-JSONL (or vice versa) program once and then use it as another tool in the shell pipeline.

```
# to_csv.py
import csv, json, sys
rows = [json.loads(line) for line in sys.stdin]
all_keys = []
for row in rows:
    for key in row.keys():
        if key not in all_keys:
            all_keys.append(key)
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=all_keys, extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writeheader()
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Usage (I had to fix the `example.json` a little bit):

```
$ cat example.json | jq -c '.base[].base[] | { uid, name }' | python3 to_csv.py
uid,name
2da21174-0af8-4b5b-b02e-2957a24d70e1,
fcc5a2c8-3a78-4cc5-9fd3-e7bd59eb36ba,Tommy
4ecf6450-7307-466c-bf19-663ba2fbaf69,Sam
```

Comment: Yes within python pyjq.all ('.base[].base[].uid, .base[].base[].name') works perfectly. BTW do you know how to cut the date only from the following value `"iso-8601": "2018-03-19T03:24-0500"`from JSON?

Comment: If in Python I would use substring :) row["iso-8601"][:10]